# Mini-satelite how to stabilize orientation?

Tags: artificial-satellite

I was watching [this video](https://www.planet.com) about how the mini-satelites of PlanetLabs are being launched from the International Space Station, and something immediately came to my mind:

**How could they point camera in the right direction?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, in a small satellite, a [reaction wheel system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_wheel) is used to turn the craft, and optical detection used to determine orientation.

[Here's a module](http://www.cubesatkit.com/docs/datasheet/DS_CSK_ADACS_634-00412-A.pdf) intended for use in CubeSats like PlanetLabs' which uses reaction wheels for orientation and, apparently, magnetometers and sun sensors (optical?) to determine orientation.